# Multiple Regression Dataset needed

Tags: data-request

I need a dataset to run a multiple regression (and find best equation) wherein

Y / Dependent Variable - is a quantitative variable There should be at least 6 X / dependent variables - which should be quantitative and one other X / dependent variable which should be categorical (2 categories OK).

Another condition is that at least some part of this dataset should be from the past year.

I have spent hours and hours on the web (Google / Kaggle) searching for one but unable to find one which meets this criteria.

Can anyone suggest me a dataset OR explain to me how to scrape any real-world data and make my own dataset which satisfies the above ? (I do not understand how to do the latter)

Thanks!